# jQuery when hover style prev and next siblings

Tags: jquery, hover, siblings

I have a nav menu

```
<ul>
  <li id="menu1">content</li>
  <li id="menu2">content</li>
  <li id="menu3">content</li>
  <li id="menu4">content</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to use jQuery so that when I hover over a li item, the style of the previous and next siblings change.

Eg; when I hover over .menu2, the border-radius for .menu1 and .menu3 changes to 8px.

I know I can't do this with pure CSS, but what would be the script using jQuery?

Comment: you strange using `class` better use `id` here

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

This will be an easier solution. Add a class in css with the styles, and toggle that class on hover with jQuery.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu li').hover(function(){
        $(this).prev().toggleClass('large-border');
        $(this).next().toggleClass('large-border');
    });
});
```

HTML (add a class to the parent):

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu1">content</li>
  <li class="menu2">content</li>
  <li class="menu3">content</li>
  <li class="menu4">content</li>
</ul>
```

Add a class with the properties in your CSS:

```
.large-border {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LaGg/)

Answer (score 1):

You may try with the class like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("div").hover(
       function(){
        jQuery(this).addClass("active");
        jQuery("div").not(".active").addClass("otherdeactive");
    },
    function(){ 
      jQuery(this).removeClass("active"); 
       jQuery("div").not(".active").removeClass("otherdeactive");
    });


});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/muthusamy/MZeTv/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jquery:

```
$('ul li a').hover(function(){
    (this).next().css('border-radius','8px');
    (this).prev().css('border-radius','8px');
},function(){
    (this).next().css('border-radius','0px');
    (this).prev().css('border-radius','0px');
});
```